# I Request Help on Implementing a General Tree in Java

Tags: java, tree, nodes

I've come up with the following as an attempt to create a general tree in java:

```
import java.util.*;

public class GeneralNode<T>{

    private T data = null;
    private Vector<GeneralNode<T>> children = 
            new Vector<GeneralNode<T>>();

    public GeneralNode(){
        this(null);
    }

    public GeneralNode(T d){
        data = d;
    }

    public Vector<GeneralNode<T>> getChildren(){
        return children;
    }

    public void addChild(T d){
        GeneralNode<T> c = new GeneralNode<T>(d);
        this.children.add(c);
    }

    public void addChild(GeneralNode<T> c){
        this.children.add(c);
    }

    public T getData(){
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T newData){
        data = newData;
    }

    public boolean isLeaf(){
        return(children.isEmpty());
    }

    public Vector getChildrenData(){
        Vector<T> result = new Vector<T>();
        for(int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++)
            result.add(children.elementAt(i).getData());
    return result;
    }
}
```

This works great for storing information. It allows me to create a node and insert more nodes in that node, along with having one type of information in each node. Unfortunately, it seems like I can't reference a "parent" node with this class. Essentially, I'm nesting vectors within vectors, so I can't actually reference the node holding the node.

I'm sure I have to make a separate GeneralTree class in order to get this done, but I'm not sure how I'd go about doing so. I had the idea of assigning the root as a GeneralNode, and having a "previous" and "next" node as being the parent and children respectively. This is what I've come up with so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class GeneralTree<T>{

    private GeneralNode<T> root;
    private GeneralNode<T> parent;
    private GeneralNode<T> children;

    public GeneralTree(){
        this(null);
    }

    public GeneralTree(T d){
        this(d, null);
    }

    /* I don't know what to do here. I want
     * to assign a parent node to every 
     * tree I make, but if I keep the
     * second parameter as GeneralNode<T>, wouldn't
     * that mean I could only ever have one GeneralTree?
     */
    public GeneralTree(T d, GeneralNode<T> p){
        root = new GeneralNode<T>(d);
        parent = p;
    }
}
```

I've written comments on the constructor I'm confused on. I hope I've explained my problem well enough. If anyone can help me with this that'd be great.

Comment: If you want nodes to know who their parents are, then you must give the class another member in which each instance stores a reference its parent, and you must manage those references when you add nodes.  In order for that to work reliably, you must avoid other objects being able to add nodes directly to any Node's list of children.  That means `getChildren()` must not return the `children` list itself -- it can instead return a copy or an immutable wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

As @JohnBollinger said, you can keep a reference of parent node inside each nodes. If you do that you must set parent nodes inside `addChild` methods.

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class GeneralNode<T>{

    private T data = null;
    private Vector<GeneralNode<T>> children = 
            new Vector<GeneralNode<T>>();

    private GeneralNode<T> parentNode;

    //constructors

    private void setParent(GeneralNode<T> parentNode) {
        this.parentNode = parentNode;
    }

    public void addChild(T d){
        GeneralNode<T> c = new GeneralNode<T>(d);
        c.setParent(this);
        this.children.add(c);
    }

    public void addChild(GeneralNode<T> c){
        c.setParent(this);
        this.children.add(c);
    }

    //other methods
}
```